# Bind the object in combo box in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, combobox

I have the data collection in the Json format as Date, Author and Description. I have two combo boxes to bind Date and Author and a text box to bind Description. How to bind all these so that if I choose the a specific date from combo box 1, it should automatically select the corresponding author in Combo box 2 and the corresponding Description in text box. I have done this early in Jquery, but not sure how to do this in Angular way. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your main scope should hold an array representing the collection you want to display on the screen.

```
$scope.collections = [
  {...},
  {...},
  {...}
];
```

Then you trigger a function selecting the appropriate data.

```
$scope.dateChanged = function () {
  var appropriateData = $scope.collections.map(function (e) { return e.date; }).indexOf($scope.date);

  if (appropriateDate > -1)
    $scope.currentObject = $scope.collections[appropriateData];
}
```

You can then create some directives in your controller binding the values using attributes :

```
<div id=box1 my-box1 author="{{ currentObject.author }}"></div>
```

I can't believe I answer this question.